# multi_heap_assert after using malloc on ESP32

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

I have this function to convert a buffer into a base64 string.

```
bool SIM7020_ToBase64(const void* p_Buffer, uint16_t Length, std::string* p_Base64)
{
    size_t EncodeLength;
    unsigned char* OutputBuffer = NULL;

    if((p_Buffer == NULL) || (p_Base64 == NULL))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Get the size for memory allocation first.
    mbedtls_base64_encode(OutputBuffer, 0, &EncodeLength, (const unsigned char*)p_Buffer, Length);

    Here >> OutputBuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * EncodeLength);
    if(OutputBuffer == NULL)
    {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Can not allocate memory!");

        return false;
    }

    // Encode the data.
    mbedtls_base64_encode(OutputBuffer, EncodeLength, &EncodeLength, (const unsigned char*)p_Buffer, Length);
    p_Base64->append(std::string((char*)OutputBuffer));

    free(OutputBuffer);

    return true;
}
```

But I got the following exceptions:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4008a92c  PS      : 0x00060a30  A0      : 0x80084dfc  A1      : 0x3ffb1ea0  
A2      : 0x3f800000  A3      : 0x00006c44  A4      : 0x00000000  A5      : 0x3ffb23c8
A6      : 0xfffffffc  A7      : 0x3ffb23c8  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0xffffffff  
A10     : 0x3f800010  A11     : 0xffffffff  A12     : 0x3f800014  A13     : 0x00000000
A14     : 0x0000000a  A15     : 0xfffffffc  SAR     : 0x00000000  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0xffffffff  LBEG    : 0x4008d76c  LEND    : 0x4008d77f  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000

ELF file SHA256: 91b60b0bac67dcc7

Backtrace: 0x4008a929:0x3ffb1ea0 0x40084df9:0x3ffb1ec0 0x40084e47:0x3ffb1ee0 0x4008d2c9:0x3ffb1f00 0x400d2cb9:0x3ffb1f20 0x400d89ee:0x3ffb1f40 0x400d8c7b:0x3ffb2160 0x4008733d:0x3ffb2180
  #0  0x4008a929:0x3ffb1ea0 in multi_heap_assert at framework-espidf\components\heap/multi_heap_platform.h:54
      (inlined by) multi_heap_malloc_impl at framework-espidf\components\heap/multi_heap.c:431
  #1  0x40084df9:0x3ffb1ec0 in heap_caps_malloc at framework-espidf\components\heap/heap_caps.c:111
  #2  0x40084e47:0x3ffb1ee0 in heap_caps_malloc_default at framework-espidf\components\heap/heap_caps.c:146
  #3  0x4008d2c9:0x3ffb1f00 in malloc at framework-espidf\components\newlib/heap.c:32
  #4  0x400d2cb9:0x3ffb1f20 in SIM7020_ToBase64(void const*, unsigned short, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) at src/SIM7020/Misc/sim7020_tools.cpp:88
```

So what is wrong here? I have a 8 MB PSRAM and the RAM is also enabled:

```
I (1206) spiram: SPI SRAM memory test OK
I (1206) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
I (1206) heap_init: At 3FFAFF10 len 000000F0 (0 KiB): DRAM
I (1212) heap_init: At 3FFB6388 len 00001C78 (7 KiB): DRAM
I (1219) heap_init: At 3FFB9A20 len 00004108 (16 KiB): DRAM
I (1225) heap_init: At 3FFBDB5C len 00000004 (0 KiB): DRAM
I (1231) heap_init: At 3FFC1288 len 0001ED78 (123 KiB): DRAM
I (1237) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM
I (1244) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM
I (1250) heap_init: At 4008EBB8 len 00011448 (69 KiB): IRAM
I (1257) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
I (1261) spiram: Adding pool of 4096K of external SPI memory to heap allocator
I (1282) spi_flash: detected chip: generic
I (1283) spi_flash: flash io: dio
I (1283) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
I (1291) spiram: Reserving pool of 32K of internal memory for DMA/internal allocations
```

So the memory shoudln´t be a problem here. I also doesn´t understand the error, i. e. doesn´t understand the reason for the error. I use esp-idf `4.0.1`.

Comment: What's the return value of `mbedtls_base64_encode`? Is `EncodeLength` a reasonable value?

Comment: The value is `27713`. The value for `Length` is 20782 and contains an embedded file.

Comment: Looks reasonable. Are you running recent version? Is the heap overly fragmented? Can't give much more advice beyond that :/

Comment: I imagine this is happening in the context of a much larger program. What happens if you write a very small program which just calls this code fragment, passing it a reasonable set of arguments?

Comment: Yes, this happens in a much larger program that is responsible for communicating with a SIM7020 module (i. e. using a lot of strings and the heap). I have tried to figure out the reason and it looks like `Serial1` is the reason. The error is gone after chaning the interface to `Serial2`.